# Is it possible to print Python output to any text box?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue, I forgot a password made only by 6-8 numbers (aprox.), to recover it Im making an easy script in **python**, I have to write the password in a text box on my browser, if the password is correct this button will be enabled.

Here is a **preview**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dawFl.png]

**code:**

```
import time

pass_ = 0

    while pass_ <= 10000000    #Here is when the bucle starts

    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(pass_)
    pass_ += 1
```

I want to print the generated number in the text input (on my browser) and wait the button to be enabled.

Comment: So instead of printing to the screen with `print(Pass)`, you want to output it into a text box on a browser? I think you will have to use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for this.

Comment: or plain javascript if you are designing a web/api